# Selecting the team which to create a repository under using terminal on Bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-api

I am calling a curl request within a bash script to create a Repository on Bitbucket using their API. We have a team setup for our development team and each of our accounts are setup as admin for this team. When I do the request I supply my username and password in the request and this creates the repository under the team associated with my account name. How can I select the team I want to create the repository under when using the Bitbucket API.

My current request is:

```
curl --user 'SRowleyAO:password' https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/ --data name=test_repository
```

Which creates a repo (test_repository) under the team SRowleyAO